# Is it possible to ask Jackson to serialize by getter/setter if and only if a field is present

Tags: java, jackson

Given this class

```
class User {
   Long id;
   String username;
   String password;
   boolean active;

   String getUsername() {
   }

   boolean isNew() {
     return id != null;
   }

   boolean isActive() {
     return active;
   }
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to globally (not via annotations on the class) to serialize this class as

```
{
  username: "foo",
  active: true, // or would it be isActive, can't remember
}
```

whilst deserializing you could set

```
{
  username: "bar",
  active: false, // or would it be isActive, can't remember
  password: "password1"
}
```

the trick that I'm looking for here is that password doesn't have a getter so it shouldn't be serialized, and isNew doesn't have a field so shouldn't be serialized. password does have a setter so input would be allowed.

I know you can set visibility for GETTER, SETTER, IS_GETTER, and FIELD, but as far as I know there's no way to say must be a property with valid reader and backing field, or valid writer with backing field.

Comment: It's possible, since you can write a custom serializer.

Comment: No need of custom desializer. Read this link for your use case: http://www.davismol.net/2015/03/21/jackson-using-jsonignore-and-jsonproperty-annotations-to-exclude-a-property-only-from-json-deserialization/